# How to display the contents of a PDF document using pdfbox in Android

Tags: android

I want to use `PDFbox` to read and display the contents of a PDF document. I can extract the text from the PDF document using `PDFTextStripper`.

My problem is how can I display all the contents in PDF document as it is? I want to display the PDF document like it is displayed in the applications like Adobe reader.  Is it possible using the PDFBox in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You could export the PDF document as images and display those. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523688/pdfbox-problem-with-converting-pdf-page-into-image).

Comment: i reviewed that code but my doubt is, can i get a PDF file layout...?