# How to convert Pdf file to doc file in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, pdftotext

how to convert pdf file into doc file and display this doc file on jeditor pane.
 please any one help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read PDF contect by using itext. Examples are there in below link

http://itextpdf.com/book/toc.php

But if the requirement is just to display PDF content than I believe you can use PDFRenderer to display PDF document.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-opensourcejava-pdf-renderer.html?page=1

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming what you want to do is read a PDF, and display its contents as text in a  JTextArea. Probably the easiest way to do this would be using [Apache's PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/index.html). The [`PDFTextStripper`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html) class should help you accomplish this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("/path/to/file.pdf"));
String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
// display in some JTextArea
```

You can find several other examples in the [tutorials](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html). If formatting is important, you can also try [converting it to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223261/473637), or use a library like [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html).

Comment: thanks for reply but second line throw exception. like this   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fontbox/afm/FontMetric

Comment: After downloading [PDFBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfbox/files/), make sure you copy all the jars in the lib folder into your project folder.