# Java Android Eclipse heap space noteough to run the pdf to jps conversion file module

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf

Sir, I am going to implement the module for converting the pdf to jpeg. At first , I can successfully create the pdf with one page. Then , I use the reference given by 
[How to create image from PDF using PDFBox in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868910/how-to-create-image-from-pdf-using-pdfbox-in-java)
to construct this model.

When it comes to building up the projects and compling, java heap space occcurs.

The below is my code

```
  protected void convertToImage(File file) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!file.exists())
        return;

    try {
        PDDocument document = null; 
        try 
        {
            document = PDDocument.load(file);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("" + ex);
        }

        List<PDPage>pages =  document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        Iterator iter =  pages.iterator(); 

        int i =1;
        String name = null;

        while (iter.hasNext()) 
        {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map pageImages = resources.getImages();
            if (pageImages != null) 
            { 
                Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
                while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages.get(key);
                    image.write2file("H:\\image" + i);
                    i ++;
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

Below is my eclipse ini section

```
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  256M
  -showsplash
  org.eclipse.platform
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  256m
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  -vmargs
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
  -Xms80m  <------cannot be further increased
  -Xmx512m  <------cannot be further increased
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to increase the heap size available to Eclipse is to edit the .ini file. You should find `eclipse.ini` in the same directory as your Eclipse executable. Specifically, increase the value for -Xmx, which represents maximum heap size:

```
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m <-- increase this, e.g. 512m
```