# iText or PDFBox for PDF snapshot?

Tags: imagemagick, itext, pdfbox

If I would like to export a specific region of a PDF page to an image with **high resolution**, which software could work?

I searched the code of iText. Although it excels at creating/manipulation, there doesn’t seems to be export/snapshot options. Or would **ImageMagick** or Apache **PDFBox** better for the job?

Feng

Comment: As far as I know, iText doesn't do rendering, but they are BFF with JPedal for the rendering. PDFBox can do rendering. You can search examples here on stackoverflow, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523688/pdfbox-problem-with-converting-pdf-page-into-image

Comment: What is BFF? Stackoverflow doesn't seem to contain link? @TilmanHausherr

Comment: BFF = "best friends forever". See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810048/extract-table-contents-from-pdf-in-java-itext-pdfbox#comment36628722_23810048 They also had a common presentation at the PDFDays this year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-QcU9B4qMc  PDFBox was there too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agzqehWt-ko

Comment: Just to add some clarity, by "image" I'm going to assume that you more specifically mean a raster image format such as JPEG/PNG/TIFF. I agree with Tilman that PDFBox is a great solution for this. If, however, you just mean a file-based format that you can crop your PDF down to, then a PDF file can actually do this for you and you can use iText. The advantage of this is that there is no resolution change so you are guaranteed to have the highest possible resolution.

Comment: Do you mean basically use iText function to change one of {Mediabox, bleeding box, containing box, etc.} properties? I think it is possible, but perhaps that modifies only several properties of the file, and suppose if you need to extract 10 images from the PDF, if you use this simple "crop" approach perhaps you need to create 10 copies of the original file, each of which almost 100% of the original PDF size, differs only in cropping box settings? @ChrisHaas