# How to convert PDF to an Image without text

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I would like to know if its possible to convert a PDF to and image without fonts. My goal is to have only the image without text ?

And if yes, can I do it with ImageMagick/GhostScript ?

Here an example

The image final http://crocodoc_public.s3.amazonaws.com/8b8aa154-45e3-41f9-a465-628e1b2e955d/images/page-001.png

and the original PDF http://crocodoc.com/demo/efwpa (page 2) We can see that the text are on overlay over the image, what I want is to do the same.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653380/converting-a-pdf-to-png

Comment: Thanks, I saw almost all questions about converting, I spent my night at this... convert PDF to an image I already can, but I would like without the fonts or to do simpler without text.

Comment: don't understand what you mean, if you convert a PDF to PNG, there are no "fonts" in the PNG. Can you explain in more detail, or (better) give an example?

Comment: I changed my question and added an example, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So if I got you right, what you want is to remove some *text* from your PDF (not *fonts*), and you want to do it programmatically. I suspect you know already that this will only possible if the text is placed on some kind of separate layer in your PDF files. You can try to utilize [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) for that. Beware, this will mean you will have to invest some days of learning how to use that library.

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking fonts, because some people have problems with text when they don't have fonts. I gave a look to iText, but I'm totally not comfortable with Java, I will try.

Comment: I tried iText and I unfortunately can't reach my goal. It seems to be that they don't have what I'm looking for.

Comment: @yvan: perhaps you should ask a new, more specific question here on SO, posting some lines of your code using iText and tell us exactly which problems occurred / what does not work. iText is a powerful tool, but usage is not always straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I too am the lookout for something like that.
While playing with imagemagick I tried this a command and got some unexpected results.

```
convert -input.pdf -blur 0x0 output.jpg
```

this removes the text layers from the pdfs I tried.

I cannot guarantee that this will work for you and if this the right way to achieve, but you may try.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Adobe Acrobat. Select the text with the touch up tool and delete it. I don't think you can do that with Ghostscript. You could consider editing the PDF by hand ([qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) helps).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know in advance how much PDFs I'm gonna have, to do each by hand gonna take a long time. But QPDF is a very interesting tool. I'm gonna consider it like a helper.