# How to read PDf files in web browsers without having Acrobat reader installed on the System?

Tags: pdf

I need to read pdf files in web browsers. My client does not want to install Acrobat reader in his system. Also I have seen another alternative Flex Paper. But as it is paid my client does not want to proceed. So is there any other alternative which can be handled from linux server
end itself?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need something on the client. Try Foxit reader. If I recall well it's free and lightweight.

Comment: @Mike..thanks. But my client does not want to do anything from client machine. Is there any software that can be installed on the server?

Comment: Maybe you could search for something that converts PDF to HTML (loosing some formatting obviously) or rely on some flash to render the PDF. (this will require at least flash support on the client)

Comment: Chrome an Firefox have a PDF viewer built in now. pdf.js (pdf.min.js) also works in Internet Explorer 10 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to automate this process or do you mind a little manual work?

One thing you could use is a free online [PDF to Flash convertor](http://www.codebox.es/pdf-to-flash-page-flip).

Another thing is to [use GhostScript to convert the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653380/converting-a-pdf-to-png) to something else like a JPG or PNG. I think GS is available for most Linux distros.