# Python PDF thumbnail preview generation

Tags: python, linux, macos, pdf-generation

I am looking for ways to generate jpeg thumbnail of pdf files.
I would like to do that in Python.
Is there any library or can anyone guide me how to do it?

Thanks

I am working on MacOS X Lion.
But I would like to run it on Ubuntu or CentOS.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include what OS you're working on - Windows/Linux/etc?

Comment: working with OS X Lion but I would like to run it on Ubuntu or CentOS

Comment: I think ImageMagick can do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653380/converting-a-pdf-to-png

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use **ImageMagick** {apt-get install imagemagick on Ubuntu} (it also has Python lib **PythonMagick**) to convert pdf to images

```
import subprocess
params = ['convert', 'pdf_file', 'thumb.jpg']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

You can also provide parameters at which the image has to generate out of the pdf like

```
params = ['convert', '-density 300 -resize 220x205', 'pdf_file', 'thumb.jpg']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

Comment: How do you handle errors like password protected file or maybe some wrong doc?

Comment: If the PDF has multiple pages, this will make one thumbnail per page. How do you limit it to only the first page?

Comment: @mlissner You can use `'pdf_file[0]'` to only generate the thumbnail for the first page.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do it grammatically, why not use an [external CLI](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-PDF-to-Image/Command-Line.ASP) tool like this:

```
os.system(r"ConvertPDFtoImage.EXE /S "C:\Input\Coffee.pdf" /T "C:\Output\Coffee.JPG" /C1  /1 * /5 200 /V")
```

for example in windows

Comment: (You should be using `subprocess`)