# Margins Disappear In PDF -> PNG Conversion with ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

I'm having troubles with converting PDF to PNG in ImageMagick.  I've used different variations, including using Ghostscript and piping the output to ImageMagic (as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379649/701410) - which doesn't seem to work for me, so I have to save to a temp file instead of using a pipe).  I've found this is working best for me:

> convert -background transparent -density 150x150 Test.pdf Test-IMSoloOut.png

Here's a screenshot of the original PDF in my viewer (Preview, on OS X):

[image: Original PDF file in Preview]

And when I convert it, I get this:

[image: PNG in Preview]

The problem is it's dropping the margins.  I'm not clear whether it's making them transparent or what, but the formatting of the image looks sloppy without the margins.

I was given this to try:

> convert -density 150x150 Test.pdf -gravity center -background transparent -extent 612x792 Test-Extras.png

And that just gives me one section of the page:

[image]

I tried adapting that and changed the 612x792 to 1275x1650, which would fit 150DPI multiplied by the size of the page (8.5" x 11").  When I did that, I got a large image, but, again, the margins were gone, like in the 2nd image above.

These images will be displayed in a Java program that will be displaying a number of pages, so the margins could vary (in other words, I can't just wrap a set border around the output, as seen in the 2nd image, since the border size will change in some images).

I've seen a number of hits on removing margins for PDF to PNG conversion, but they don't seem to provide anything to help me.

My guess is that, in the conversion process, the margins are converted to something transparent, so I tried adding "-transparent white" to the command line for convert, but it didn't help.

What can I do to either get the margins back or, if they're there and not visible, how can I get them to display?  Basically I want the PNG file (image #2) to look like the PDF file with margins included (image #1).

I suspect I'm missing something obvious - I hope it's that easy.

How can I make sure the space in the margins show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never got an exact answer, but one of the ImageMagick people was quite helpful with this.  Basically, I needed to use the option "-extent" to specify how big the image was.  Since I was using a different density than the default, I had to take that into account, too.  The command line that worked was:

> convert -density 150x150 InputFile.pdf -background white -units PixelsPerInch -density 150 -extent 1275x1650 OutputFile.png

The 1275x1650 comes from multiplying 150 (for the DPI) by 8.5" for the width and by 11 for the height.

Comment: I needed `extent` even without the density. Without the extent, the slides were cropped.