# How to use images in PDF format within Markdown source which Pandoc converts to HTML?

Tags: pandoc

I am writing a report in markdown which contains many figures generated in .pdf format. when converting to html using pandoc these images are inserted as objects in a very small box.

My question is whether it is possible to render them as pandoc would for .png for instance.

Comment: first [convert PDF to PNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653380/converting-a-pdf-to-png)?

Comment: Yes, that would be an option, however (i) the pdfs are in different folders. I am now creating a PDF the markdown which is fine for now.

Comment: I don't know what is the useful answer but I guess that `pandoc` alone will not be able to solve your problem in a single step. If you edit your question and add the script that you use to call the pandoc and some [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then it may make your question more on-topic, more clear, less broad and more attractive to some potential answerers

Comment: PDFs aren't normally found directly in HTML. You should really convert them first.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow that strategy in future projects. Cheers.