# itextsharp color picker for a area

Tags: fonts, colors, itext

I needed to insert some text (a ID)  in a location on a PDF file.This task was simple enough but I'm running in to an issue when there is color under the font location.

I need  to test to see what color(if any) is under a defined area.
Then determine if the font color should be Black or White.

I found a great routine [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855884/determine-font-color-based-on-background-color) (on StackOverflow). to help determine what color to use based on a color you send it. I was hoping to see if there was anyway to find that information out using ITextSharp.

any help would be great!

Comment: Essentially you'll have to render the PDF page section in question and check the color of the rendered image.

Comment: Is there any to export a section of a pdf to a image?

Comment: @Chris' answer points towards Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. The color that a human eye would perceive at any specific `x,y` coordinate falls under the realm of a PDF renderer which iText is not.

If I were you I would use [Ghostscript to convert the PDF to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379649/231316) such as a PNG or JPEG and then load that into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object and call [`GetPixel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is there any to export a section of a pdf to a image?

Comment: Probably, but it would be way easier to just perform two passes, PDF to bitmap (JPEG, PNG, etc) and then crop it.